# is it possible to have a matrix of matrices in R?

Tags: r

is it possible to have a matrix of matrices in R? if yes, how should I define such matrix?
for example to have a 10 x 10 matrix, and each element of this matrix contains a matrix itself.

Comment: this question is about having a list inside a matrix, mine is about having a matrix inside a matrix. since the definition of a matrix is different from list, I think my question is different. but thank you for the warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1) list/matrix** Yes, create a list and give it dimensions using `matrix`:

```
m <- matrix(1:4, 2)
M <- matrix(list(m, 2*m, 3*m, 4*m), 2)
```

so element 1,1 of `M` is `m`:

```
> M[[1,1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

**2) list/dim<-** This also works:

```
M <- list(m, 2*m, 3*m, 4*m)
dim(M) <- c(2, 2)
```

**3) array** This is not quite what you asked for but depending on your purpose it might satisfy your need:

```
A <- array(c(m, 2*m, 3*m, 4*m), c(2, 2, 2, 2)) # 2x2x2x2 array
```

so element 1,1 is:

```
> A[1,1,,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Comment: that was fast, tanx a lot, that's exactly what I need