# Summing matrices inside matrices when they are stored as lists

Tags: r

With the help of another thread I was able to construct the following matrix, with 100 diagonal matrices inside each of equal dimension 100 by 100:

```
Sigma_inverse<-lapply(seq(n), function(k) (diag(seq(n)))^(2*k+1))
```

I have another matrix S which is 100 by 100. If I sum the matrices as in the following code, it works.

```
S+Sigma_inverse[[1]]
```

However, if I try to create another matrix with 100 lists, of matrices 100 by 100 and sum the first element which is or I expect to be a 100 by 100 matrix as in the following code:

```
S_alpha_dim[[1]]+Sigma_inverse[[1]]
```

I get the following error:

```
> S_alpha_dim[[1]]+Sigma_inverse[[1]]
Error: dims [product 10000] do not match the length of object [1000000]
```

So I proceeded to check the dimension of the matrix S_alpha_dim[[1]]

```
> dim(S_alpha_dim[[1]])
NULL
```

which is null but this later matrix is supposed to be matrix S which is a 100 by 100 matrix as it is attested by the following:

```
> dim(S)
[1] 100 100
```

So I began to suspect that R is not recognizing the lists as matrices inside a matrix. However, I followed this thread where it was advised to use lists to express matrices within matrices. [is it possible to have a matrix of matrices in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-matrix-of-matrices-in-r)

**Question:**

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Update:

As a reference matrix for S, so that the code can be reproduced, it similar to use the following construction with a 2 by 2 matrix that renders the same problem:

```
matrix_eksa<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)

> matrix_eksa_1<-matrix(list(rep(matrix_eksa,100)),100)
> dim(matrix_eksa_1[1])
NULL
```

Comment: Seems `S_alpha_dim[[1]]` isn't a matrix. You'd better show a small example for it.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Please see my update.

Comment: What is `matrix_eksa`?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding ```matrix_eksa<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `rep(list(...),100)`, rather than `list(rep(...,100))`, i.e.,

```
matrix_eksa_1 <- matrix(rep(list(matrix_eksa), 100), 100)
```

then you will see

```
> matrix_eksa <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)

> matrix_eksa_1 <- matrix(rep(list(matrix_eksa), 100), 100)

> dim(matrix_eksa_1)
[1] 100   1
```

Comment: ```                                                                                                                                                              > matrix_eksa_1<- matrix(rep(list(matrix_eksa), 100), 100)
> dim(matrix_eksa_1[1])
NULL```

Comment: @MagnusMoller you should use `matrix_eksa_1[[1]]`. `matrix_eksa_1[1]` is a list, it has no dimensions.

Comment: Still getting the same null dimension.